# how to copy all data in a row to all other rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
<table id="ratecardlist">
    <tr>
        <th> Show Time</th>
        <th> Balcony </th>
        <th> Box </th>
        <th> &nbsp; </th>
    </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>10.30AM</td>           
       <td><input type="text" name="bal:1:3" value="100" /> </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="box:1:5" value="200" /> </td>
       <td><a href="#" onClick="applytoAll();">Apply To All</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>1.30PM</td>           
       <td><input type="text" name="bal:3:3" value="400" /> </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="box:3:5" value="450"/> </td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
       <td>6.30PM</td>           
       <td><input type="text" name="bal:5:3" value="600" /> </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="box:5:5" value="600" /> </td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
       .
       .
       .
</table>
```

Apply to All link will always in second row. When I Click **Apply To All**, input values in this row should copy to other rows input fields. How to do that plz Help.

e.g.
After click Apply To All,

```
   <table id="ratecardlist">
    <tr>
        <th> Show Time</th>
        <th> Balcony </th>
        <th> Box </th>
    </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>10.30AM</td>           
       <td><input type="text" name="bal:1:3" value="100" /> </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="box:1:5" value="200" /> </td>
       <td><a href="#" onClick="applytoAll();">Apply To All</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>1.30PM</td>           
       <td><input type="text" name="bal:3:3" value="100" /> </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="box:3:5" value="200"/> </td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
       <td>6.30PM</td>           
       <td><input type="text" name="bal:5:3" value="100" /> </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="box:5:5" value="200" /> </td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
       .
       .
       .
</table>
```

Comment: Did you try anything? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I tried several things but couldn't get the result. I used clone method but it is not worked as show times values can not be changed only the input field values should be replaced.

Comment: Your markup is flawed. Use class names to refer to similar elements (blacony inputs and box inputs), also, why is there an entire column with `&nbsp;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the way you're handling the `click` event does not provide enough context (e.g. the clicked element) to the handler. Ideally, you would decorate your link with an `id` or a `class` attribute and use that to register the handler unobtrusively (through jQuery's [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method, for instance).

If you're stuck with your current strategy, you should at least pass the clicked element to the handler:

```
<a href="#" onClick="applyToAll(this);">Apply To All</a>
```

From there, you can implement the function as follows:

```
function applyToAll(element)
{
    // Build an array with the values of this row, in document order.
    var $row = $(element).closest("tr");
    var values = $row.find("input:text").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    // Apply the values to the other rows.
    $row.nextAll().each(function() {
        $(this).find("input:text").each(function(index) {
            $(this).val(values[index]);
        });
    });
}
```

This solution supports an arbitrary number of input elements per row, not just two.

Answer (score 2):

This is crude but should work:

```
function applyToAll()
{
 var bal_val = this.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].value;
 var box_val = this.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[2].childNodes[0].value;
 var inps = this.parentNodes.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input');

 for (i=0; i<inps.length; i++)
 {
  inp = inps[i];
  inp.value = bal_val;
  inp = inps[i+1];
  inp.value = box_val;
  i++;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are using jQuery:

```
$('#ratecardlist a').click(function(){
   var balVal = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[name^=bal]').val();
   var boxVal = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[name^=box]').val();
   $('#ratecardlist td[name^=bal]').val(balVal);
   $('#ratecardlist td[name^=box]').val(boxVal);
});
```

Comment: If the columns are adding randomly, how do I do this.

Comment: this function works for any number of rows, that follow the same standards, having inputs with name starting with bal and box.

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadezyes Yes Yes this is working fine. but the problem is if the columns are adding randomly how to fix this.

Comment: There can be column for 'ODC' then I have to add  `var odcVal = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[name^=odc]').val();`. But If the columns are adding dynamically how I do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('#applyToAll').click(function(){
        var ctx = $(this).closest('tr');
        $('input[name^="bal"]').val($('input[name^="bal"]', ctx).val());
        $('input[name^="box"]').val($('input[name^="box"]', ctx).val());
        return false;
    });
});
```

And here is the [code demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EvaP8/1/).